# Geometric distribution problem stochastic process

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I was solving a problem from Introduction to sthocastic process and I get stucked in a finding a distribution, hope you can help me.

So the problem is this:
There's a Markov chain with space of states $S:=\{1, \cdots c,c+1, \cdots c+d  \} $ Let's define $A:=\{1, \cdots c\}$ and $B:=\{c+1, \cdots c+d\}$ ,$X_n$ take values in $S$, the transition function is given by:
$P(x,y)= 1/d$, in case $x\in A \land y \in B$, and $P(x,y)= 1/c$, in case $x\in B \land y \in A$, and $0$ otherwise.

If $T_x$ means the first time of return to $x$, I want to calculate the distribution of $T_x$...

So... Without of loss of generality I can suppose $x\in A$, then I can only come back to $x$ in an even number of steps (see the transiction function),

So in general I need to prove that:

$$P_x(T_x=2k)=\frac{1}{c} \cdot \left( \frac{c-1}{c} \right)^{k-1} $$ for $k\geq1$ The $P_x$ means the probability with $X_0=x$

For example the case $k=1$ seems easy:
$$P_x(T_x=2)= \sum_{i=c+1}^{d}P(x,i)P(i,x)=d\frac{1}{d} \frac{1}{c} =\frac{1}{c}$$

But then when I try $P_x(T_x=4)$, I can't get the result, I tried this:

$$P_x(T_x=4)=\sum_{k\in B}\sum_{j\in A\setminus \{x\}} \sum_{i\in B}P(x,i)P(i,j)P(j,k)P(k,x)$$

But i don't get what i want... The approach seems to be wrong? How would you do it?

Comment: Conditioned on $\{X_0=x\}$, the first return to $x$ occurs at time $2k$ precisely when the first $k-1$ transitions from $B$ are to $A\setminus\{x\}$ and the $k^{\mathsf{th}}$ transition from $B$ is to $x$ - which has probability $\frac1c\left(\frac{c-1}c\right)^{k-1}$.  I'm not sure what's unclear.

Comment: @Math1000 yes I understand that part, but those probabilities are every time we get to the set '$A$' (a total of k steps) and the other k steps it take values on '$B$' my conjecture is the probabilities when we are in $B$ it's a $1$ like in the case $T_x=2$ I described, but in the general case I can't see it

Comment: You may use mathematical induction to show that the probability of being in $B$ in the odd steps is $1$.